# How python interpreter decide id number?

Tags: python, python-2.7, interpreter, python-internals

I learned that id(1) always same because of interning mechanism.

```
>>> id(1)
14710976
>>> id(1)
14710976
>>> 5
>>> id(1)
14710976
>>>
```

But when i try **id(2000000000)**, it will intern too if execute id(2000000000) continuosly, but this id will changed after it execute something else (e.g. give print a number). And the id has been reuse every three times of id changing.

As you can see on the session below, 3 ids, **142989240**, **142989252**, **142989132**:

```
>>> id(2000000000)
142989240
>>> id(2000000000)
142989240
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
142989252
>>> id(2000000000)
142989132
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
142989132
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
142989240
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
142989252
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
142989132
>>>
```

**1st question：** Why python reuse the id every 3 times? Is there any concerns of python contributors agree to choose 3, not 2 or 4? In which file in the python source code can i find out the 3 times implementation?

**2nd question:**

I find out if **interned two times**

```
>>> id(2000000000)
161535928
>>> id(2000000000)
161535928
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
161535940
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
161535820
```

or **interned five times**

```
>>> id(2000000000)
161195960
>>> id(2000000000)
161195960
>>> id(2000000000)
161195960
>>> id(2000000000)
161195960
>>> id(2000000000)
161195960
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
161195972
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
161195852
```

, then the **next 2 ids, will ALWAYS end with the same single digits**. As you can see on the session above, after id(2000000000) interned, both 161535940 and 161535820 end with digit 0. After id(2000000000) interned 5 times, both 161195972 and 161195852 end with digit 2.

But if **interned once/three/four/six times**, then  i always get **3 ids which was ending in different digits**. As you can see on the session below, the interpreter session shows that 140613560, 140613476, and 140613572 ending with 0, 6, 2 respectively.

```
>>> id(2000000000)
140613560
>>> id(2000000000)
140613560
>>> id(2000000000)
140613560
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
140613476
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
140613572
```

So my question is, why this constant behavior occur and how it implemented?

**3rd question:**

Related to 2nd question, if **intern two or five times**, there are special behavior occur.

```
>>> id(2000000000)
141371320
>>> id(2000000000)
141371320
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
141371332
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
141371212
>>> 
>>> id(2000000000)
141371212
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
141371236
>>> 5
5
>>> id(2000000000)
141371320
```

Look at the middle of the session above, i press ENTER and leave empty **>>>** , and the 3 ids reused (refer to 1st question) is changed ! **141371320 -> 141371332 -> 141371212** become **141371212 -> 141371236 -> 141371320**. And i reproduced the step and find out the total is **4 ids candidates** in the sequence of **141371320 -> 141371332 -> 141371212 -> 141371236**

My question was, why this special behavior exist?

Comment: Whoa, please ease back on the images! You are all dealing with *text* here, please copy and paste that text into your question. Also, you are making your question *way too broad* by asking multiple different questions in one post.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3402717/2642204).

Comment: I will change it to text, but please give me some time, thanks.

Comment: @林果皞 This question is already on hold, so you will not receive answers on it.

Comment: @林果皞 You are allowed to ask several questions though. The 4th one is ... _interesting_.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: there are no separate memory areas. You can simply end up using a memory address that uses an integer number larger than `sys.maxint` and then you get a long int in Python 2.

Comment: And none of the behaviour is 'special', just an emergent property of how the system stores and releases objects as reference counts go up and down.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oups. I didn't pay close enough attention to the numbers :/

Comment: Python does allocate some types of objects in their own "arenas" (chunks of memory), which may explain some of the differences you're seeing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters already answered my 4th question here, so no point i open new question for 4th.  But the first three questions is related to each other and i will be blamed if put it to 3 new questions. Thanks.