# Slicing a file in Python

Tags: python, file, buffer, arrays

I have been recently working on a scripts that takes file, chunks it and analyze each piece. Because the chunking positions depend on the content, I need to read it one byte at a time. I do not need random access, just reading it linearly from beginning to end, selecting certain positions as I go and yielding the content of the chunk from the previous selected position to the current one.

It was very convenient to use a memory mapped file wrapped by a `bytearray`. Instead of yielding the chunk, I yield the offset and size of the chunk, leaving the outer function to slice it.

It was also faster than accumulating the current chunk in a `bytearray` (and much faster than accumulating in `bytes`!). But I have certain concerns that I would like to address:

1. Is bytearray copying the data?
2. I open the file as `rb` and the `mmap` with `access=mmap.ACCESS_READ`. But `bytearray` is, in principle, a mutable container. Is this a performance problem? Is there a read only container that I should use?
3. Because I do not accumulate in the buffer, I am random accessing the `bytearray` (and therefore the underlying file). Even though it might be buffered, I am afraid that there will problems depending on the file size and system memory. Is this really a problem?

Comment: Are you able to read the sources? https://www.python.org/downloads/source/ it is in the Objects folder.

Comment: @User Thanks for the tip. So bytearray is copying the data. I am using bytearray to avoid calling `ord` in each step of the loop. In a way, what I would need is something like `numpy.memmap(<filename>, dtype='uint8', mode='r')` which allows me to iterate throught the bytes (in the integer representation)

Comment: What Python version? Also, how are you wrapping `mmap` in your `bytearray`?

Comment: @Veedrac I am targeting 2.7 and 3.4. Right now, I am just doing bytearray(mmap(<etc>))

Comment: Ah, I'm pretty sure that the call copies the contents of the `mmap`. `bytearray` can't "wrap" `mmap` like that. If you want to support both 2.7 and 3.4 you'll probably be better off using Numpy (eg. [`numpy.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html)). This supports copy-free slicing. I've not used it but I would note the "An alternative to using this" section.

Comment: @Veedrac Hi have use memmap and works nicely, but I would like something that does not requires numpy. Will keep looking, thanks a lot!

Comment: On Python 3 you can use `memoryview` but `mmap` doesn't support the `memoryview` protocol on 2.x.

Comment: for the first question, I assume bytearray doesn't copy the data.  bytearray contains numbers between 0-256.  
The current implementation **keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256**, when you create an int **in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object**.

[Stackoverflow question Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402679/identifying-objects-why-does-the-returned-value-from-id-change)

Comment: Although your explanation is pretty detailed, a piece of code would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Converting one object to a mutable object does incur data copying. You can directly read the file to a bytearray by using:

   ```
   f = open(FILENAME, 'rb')
   data = bytearray(os.path.getsize(FILENAME))
   f.readinto(data)
   ```

from http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/28/less-copies-in-python-with-the-buffer-protocol-and-memoryviews#id12

2. There is a string to bytearray conversion, so there is potential  performance issue.
3. bytearray is an array, so it can hit the limit of PY_SSIZE_T_MAX/sizeof(PyObject*). For more info, you can visit
   [How Big can a Python Array Get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855191/how-big-can-a-python-array-get)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this little hack.

```
import mmap

class memmap(mmap.mmap):
    def read_byte(self):
        return ord(super(memmap,self).read_byte())
```

Create a class that inherits from the mmap class and overwrites the default read_byte that returns a string of length 1 to one that returns a int. And then you could use this class as any other mmap class.

I hope this helps.