# copy.copy() vs copy.deepcopy() : no changes in id(object)

Tags: python, deep-copy, shallow-copy

```
import copy

a = [12, 13, 15, 15, 14, 10]

d = copy.deepcopy(a)

print(id(d) == id(a))
print(id(d[0]) == id(a[0]))

e = copy.copy(a)

print(id(e) == id(a))
print(id(e[0]) == id(a[0]))

#outputs
False
True
False
True
```

I am using Python 3.4 and according to [What exactly is the difference between shallow copy, deepcopy and normal assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignm/29635219#29635219), for `d` I should get outputs `False` and `False`, for `e` I should get outputs `False` and `True`.

Any ideas why this is happening?

After I changed `a` to `[12, 13, 15, 15, 14, [10, 12]]` and then checked `id(d[5])` vs `id(a[5])` the IDs were different. So, why aren't the IDs different for `d[0]` and `a[0]`?

Comment: Don't rely on `id` for immutables like integers or strings; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402679/identifying-objects-why-does-the-returned-value-from-id-change

Comment: With immutable objects, it doesn't really matter whether you get a new object or a reference to the old one, as you can't change it in-place either way.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies... And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/pythons-is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers helped as well.. Thanks