# When the Python interpreter deals with a .py file, is it different from dealing with a single statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Running:

```
a = 257
b = 257
print id(a) == id(b)
```

Results in:

[image: same statement]
[image]

Same statement but opposite results. Why?

Comment: Why are you comparing integers by ID?

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402679/identifying-objects-why-does-the-returned-value-from-id-change interpreter might not cache those number, because it does not know if you're going to reuse it

Comment: @Hacketo: That's different.  This question is about two variables that are equivalent integers having the same id when run from a file, but different id's when run in the shell.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It is a special number. Values between -5 and 256 are preallocated. So I test 257

Comment: One point is that python has some kind of small memory of range of integer numbers, and they always will have same id. But in this case, it's really something weird

Comment: @Abirdcfly I know that, but why are you doing it *at all?* This is just implementation detail.

Comment: If a and b are declared together then the output is True.                     >>> a, b = 257, 257
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because I am reading the source code and I just try.

Comment: [>>>257 is 257](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)In fact,I find this question's answer may be same to this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The code in `test.py` is parsed together which is more optimizable than the code parsed as separate statements in the interpreter

When you put it in a `test.py` and run it *as a whole*, the byte code compiler has a better chance of analyzing the usage of literals and optimizing them. (Hence you get `a` and `b` pointing to the same place)

As opposed to when you run the separate statements (parsed separately) in the interpreter (where I think it only optimizes up to 256 but not 257 via preallocation)

Play with this in the interpreter to see the effect of separate statements:

```
>>> a, b = 257, 257      # or if you prefer: a = 257; b = 257
>>> print a is b
True

>>> a = 257
>>> b = 257
>>> print a is b
False
```

Defining a function in the interperter also gives it a change to analyze and optimize the used literals

```
>>> def test():
...     a = 257
...     b = 257
...     print a is b
... 
>>> test()
True
```

### This optimization is not limited to integers only, works e.g. for floats too (floats are not subject to a cache like integers in the [`[-5, 256]`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong) range are)

```
>>> def test():
...     pi = 3.14
...     x = 3.14
...     return x is pi
... 
>>> test()
True

# As opposed to separate statements:
>>> pi = 3.14
>>> x = 3.14
>>> x is pi
False
```

### Looking at the byte code to see that it indeed reuses the same constant

```
>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (3.14)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (pi)

  3           6 LOAD_CONST               1 (3.14) <-- Same constant 1 reused
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (x)

  4          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (pi)
             18 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: From the comments, the OP knows that "The current implementation keeps an array of integer objects for all integers between -5 and 256, when you create an int in that range you actually just get back a reference to the existing object." from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong).

Comment: I'm with you, but can we dig more ? :)