# How is this possible as id() is expected to give diffrent numbers everytime?

Tags: python-3.x

As shown in image output for id(y) and id(x[0]) is the same. How is it possible if id() is returning address of variables.

[image]

Comment: This is due to caching used by python. Python caches small integers.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402679/identifying-objects-why-does-the-returned-value-from-id-change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [identifying objects, why does the returned value from id(...) change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402679/identifying-objects-why-does-the-returned-value-from-id-change)

Comment: Then is it means that id() is not returning address??