# Python: How do I make a referenced element in a array update automatically?

Tags: python

I made a class which looks like this:

```
import numpy.random as rand
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0
    def roll(self):
        self.x=int(rand.randint(1,7,1))
        print(self.x)
```

Now, I want to roll two dices and make an array with the results.

```
A=Dice()
B=Dice()
aaa=[A.x, B.x]
print(aaa)

A.roll()
B.roll()
print(aaa)
```

The results look like:

```
[0, 0]
2
4
[0, 0]
```

What I wanted this code to act is to make the array update itself whenever the number inside changes. I know that I can make this with making another function, but is there any other ways to make this work more elegantly?

Comment: You cannot mutate an `int` object, but you can mutate your `Dice` objects. In other words, *the number inside the list never changes*. Keep your `Dice` objects in the list (not array) instead of `int` objects

Comment: as an aside, why on earth involve `numpy` in this? Just use `import random`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402679/identifying-objects-why-does-the-returned-value-from-id-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, the value in `aaa` is fixed once that line gets excuted. You should save the instances of Dice. And the `repr` method is used to pass info inside class out.

```
import numpy.random as rand
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0
    def roll(self):
        self.x=int(rand.randint(1,7,1))
        print(self.x)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.x)
A=Dice()
B=Dice()
aaa=[A, B]
print(aaa)

A.roll()
B.roll()
print(aaa)
```

Result:

```
[0, 0]
4
6
[4, 6]
```

Comment: Yeap, It's true ✅

Answer (score 0):

you could keep track of your rolls in a list, and append new ones like this:

```
import numpy.random as rand
class Dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=0
        self.dicelist = []
    def roll(self):
        self.x=int(rand.randint(1,7,1))
        self.dicelist.append(self.x)
        return self.dicelist
A=Dice()
A.roll()
A.roll()
A.roll()
print(A.roll())
#[3, 1, 4, 2]
```